# How to output specific values with XPathQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath

When I do

```
account[@id=15]
```

I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <account id="15" first_name="Sandra" last_name="Schlichting">
    <private_address address_id="19" />
    <profile_employee fk_id="15">
      <date_created>2011-1-2T1:1:00</date_created>
      <address building="3" room="2" floor="1" />
    </profile_employee>
    <profile_student fk_id="15">
      <address address_id="19" />
    </profile_student>
    <profile_student fk_id="15">
      <address address_id="45" />
    </profile_student>
  </account>
</root>
```

but I would like to just output the values of

- first_name
- last_name
- building
- room

Can someone figure out how to do that?

**Update:**

These commands works

```
account[@id=15]/profile_employee
account[@id=15]/profile_employee/address
```

but outputs entire elements, and not just the attributes room and building.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**While @Flack's answer is correct, the wanted result can be produced with a single XPath expression:**

```
concat('&#xA;', /*/account[@id=15]/@first_name,
       ' ', /*/account[@id=15]/@last_name,
       ' : ', /*/account[@id=15]/profile_employee/address/@building,
       '/', /*/account[@id=15]/profile_employee/address/@room
       )
```

**When this XPath expression is evaluated on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <account id="15" first_name="Sandra" last_name="Schlichting">
        <private_address address_id="19" />
        <profile_employee fk_id="15">
            <date_created>2011-1-2T1:1:00</date_created>
            <address building="3" room="2" floor="1" />
        </profile_employee>
        <profile_student fk_id="15">
            <address address_id="19" />
        </profile_student>
        <profile_student fk_id="15">
            <address address_id="45" />
        </profile_student>
    </account>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Sandra Schlichting : 3/2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
/root/account[@id=15]/@first_name
/root/account[@id=15]/@last_name
/root/account[@id=15]/profile_employee/address/@building
/root/account[@id=15]/profile_employee/address/@room
```

If tested in XSLT against your sample, result will be (linebreaks for clarity):

```
Sandra
Schlichting
3
2
```

Comment: When I try that I get `XPath: unable to find /root in the schema`. If I remove `/root` I get `XPath: only direct object access may select an attribute. Either change the XPath to select an element, or else use direct object access`.

Comment: @Sandra. What are you using as a hosting language for XPath?

Comment: Perl on Linux. The server is some kind of Microsoft server.

Comment: These are very odd messages. It looks like the problem is specific to your XPath processor or the environment in which it is used.

Comment: I have accepted the solution as it should work. It is just our server that is badly configured.